# Bind Parent/sibling properties in JQ to use in dynamic conditionals

Tags: json, jq

I want to create a JQ function that allows me to 
to filter an array in the JSON tree, based on parent's / sibling properties;

1 - I want to wrap function but i can't due to the scope of parent;
2 - I want to invoke that function but with other properties;

Some dummy Data:

```
[
 {
        "storeId": "s2",
        "storehouseInfo": {
            "id": "025453",
            "name": "00211 NW, OR",
            "maxPallets": 10
        },
        "workorder":{
            "id": "w2s2",
            "startDate": "2019-09-06T10:00:00.000Z",
            "vendorId":"v2"
        },
        "events": [    
            {
                "id": "e4",
                "storeId": "s2",
                "vendorId": "v1",
                "startDate": "2019-09-05T10:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2019-09-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "palletsUsed": 5
            },
            {
                "id": "e5",
                "storeId": "s2",
                "vendorId": "v2",
                "startDate": "2019-09-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2019-09-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "palletsUsed": 5
            },
            {
                "id": "e10",
                "storeId": "s2",
                "vendorId": "v1",
                "startDate": "2019-09-06T10:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2019-09-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "palletsUsed": 5
            },
            {
                "id": "e11",
                "storeId": "s2",
                "vendorId": "v2",
                "startDate": "2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2019-09-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "palletsUsed": 5
            },
            {
                "id": "e12",
                "storeId": "s2",
                "vendorId": "v2",
                "startDate": "2019-09-06T10:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2019-09-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "palletsUsed": 5
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Current working function:

```
. | map( . as $parent | 
         .
         + 
         {
            "conflictsInPeriod":
             [.events[] | (
                 getFieldsThatCheckConditionInArray(
                 # conditions
                 ( 
                    ( ($parent.workorder.startDate | dateDaysAgo(12*7) ) < .endDate)
                                and
                    (.vendorId == $parent.workorder.vendorId)
                  );
                  # props  we want to return
                 {
                     event:.id,
                     wo_sd: $parent.workorder.startDate[:10],
                     workorder_id: $parent.workorder.id
                 })   
             )]
          }
       )
```

Some aux functions:

```
def generateConflictArray(arrayName;arrayToCheck;conflictToCheck):
        map( . +
                {
                    (arrayName): [arrayToCheck | (conflictToCheck)]
                }
        );

def getFieldsThatCheckConditionInArray(condition;returnValues) :
        if (condition) then (returnValues) else empty end;
```

Desired Function CALL:

```
 . | generateConflictArray(
        "conflictsInPeriod";
        .events[];
        getFieldsThatCheckConditionInArray(
          # conditions
          ( 
                ( ($parent.workorder.startDate | dateDaysAgo(12*7) ) < .endDate)
                                and
                   (.vendorId == $parent.workorder.vendorId)
          );
           # props we want to return
           {
               event:.id,
               event_endDate:.endDate,
               wo_sd: $parent.workorder.startDate[:10],
               workorder_id: $parent.workorder.id
           })   
        )
```

Desired Output (All the array data, + newly created array " "conflictsInPeriod"", **inside each element of the array**):

```
[
{
 "conflictsInPeriod":[
      {
        "event": "e5",
        "workorder_sd": "2019-09-06",
        "workorder_id": "w2s2"
      },
      {
        "event_id": "e11",
        "workorder_sd": "2019-09-06",
        "workorder_id": "w2s2"
      },
      {
        "event_id": "e12",
        "workorder_sd": "2019-09-06",
        "workorder_id": "w2s2"
      }
]
}
]
...
```

Comment: Where is `def dateDaysAgo`?

Comment: Also I think under .workorder you probably meant `"vendorId":"v2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is closer to what you're looking for:

```
def etl(keyname; arrayname; cond; result):
  def etl:
    . as $parent
    | .[arrayname][]
    | { parent: $parent, child: .}
    | select(cond) | result;

  {(keyname): map(etl)}
 ;

## Invocation:
etl("conflictsInPeriod";
    "events";
    ( (.parent.workorder.startDate | dateDaysAgo(12*7) ) < .child.endDate)
      and
      (.child.vendorId == .parent.workorder.vendorId);
   {
     event: .child.id,
     wo_sd: .parent.workorder.startDate[:10],
     workorder_id: .parent.workorder.id
   }
)
```

Notice how the conditions are written in relation to `.parent` and `.child` rather than `$parent` and `.`.

Comment: Thank you, for the response, have created a new one, instead of editing this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57573760/2835192

Answer (score 0):

It may be that one cannot achieve in jq what you think you want, but the following comes close:

```
def etl( array; cond; result):
  array[]
  | if cond then result else empty end ;

{conflictsInPeriod: map(
  . as $parent
  | etl(.events;
       ( ($parent.workorder.startDate | dateDaysAgo(12*7) ) < .endDate)
       and
       (.vendorId == $parent.workorder.vendorId);
       {
         event:.id,
         wo_sd: $parent.workorder.startDate[:10],
         workorder_id: $parent.workorder.id
       }
    )
  )
}
```